# Remove www. in directory only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, no-www

I'm trying to remove the `www.` for a single directory called **dir** (for example). I need to be able to do this from the `.htaccess` file in that directory. (I don't have root access.) Any idea how to make this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com/dir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/dir$1 [R=301,L]
```

Update—the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP_HOST will not contain the path being accessed you need to match that in the rewrite rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir\/(.*)$ http://example.com/dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The makes perfect sense—thank you! I still didn't get it to work though...updating the question.

Comment: Got it! Because I'm using the .htaccess in /dir/ I don't need 'dir' in the first part of the RewriteRule (like I would if in the root level .htaccess). Thanks again :)